# How to use css grid centering but keep grid child from extending above top of screen on small screen heigh

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a div with with a min-height restriction which I center by applying the following css to the parent container:

```
#okta-signin-container{
  display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    place-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The issue is if i collapse the height of the screen the login child div is extending above the screen and is getting chopped off. Any way to keep it from extending above the screen and enabling scroll?

Here is my full html block:

```
    <div data-v-abf56ef8="" class="login">
   <div data-v-abf56ef8="" id="grid-container-small">
      <div data-v-abf56ef8="" class="login-block-small">
         <div data-v-abf56ef8="" class="login mobile">
            <div id="okta-signin-container">
               <main data-se="auth-container" tabindex="-1" id="okta-sign-in" class="auth-container main-container no-beacon" style="">
                  <div class="okta-sign-in-header auth-header">
                     <h1><img src="/src/assets/img/Logo-Vertical-Grey-Version.png" class="auth-org-logo" alt=" logo" aria-label=" logo"></h1>
                     <div data-type="beacon-container" class="beacon-container"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth-content">
                     <div class="auth-content-inner">
                        <div class="siw-main-view identify--okta_password primary-auth">
                           <div class="siw-main-header">
                              <div></div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="siw-main-body">
                              <form method="POST" action="/login" data-se="o-form" slot="content" id="form20" class="ion-form o-form o-form-edit-mode">
                                 <div data-se="o-form-content" class="o-form-content o-form-theme clearfix">
                                    <h2 data-se="o-form-head" class="okta-form-title o-form-head">Welcome</h2>
                                    <div class="o-form-info-container"></div>
                                    <div class="o-form-error-container" data-se="o-form-error-container"></div>
                                    <div class="o-form-fieldset-container" data-se="o-form-fieldset-container">
                                       <div data-se="o-form-fieldset-identifier" class="o-form-fieldset o-form-label-top">
                                          <div data-se="o-form-label" class="okta-form-label o-form-label"><label for="input28">Username&nbsp;</label></div>
                                          <div data-se="o-form-input-container" class="o-form-input"><span data-se="o-form-input-identifier" class="o-form-input-name-identifier o-form-control okta-form-input-field input-fix"><input type="text" placeholder="" name="identifier" id="input28" value="" aria-label="" autocomplete="username"></span></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div data-se="o-form-fieldset-credentials.passcode" class="o-form-fieldset o-form-label-top">
                                          <div data-se="o-form-label" class="okta-form-label o-form-label"><label for="input36">Password&nbsp;</label></div>
                                          <div data-se="o-form-input-container" class="o-form-input"><span data-se="o-form-input-credentials.passcode" class="o-form-input-name-credentials.passcode o-form-control okta-form-input-field input-fix"><input type="password" placeholder="" name="credentials.passcode" id="input36" value="" aria-label="" autocomplete="current-password" class="password-with-toggle"><span class="password-toggle"><span class="eyeicon visibility-16 button-show"></span><span class="eyeicon visibility-off-16 button-hide"></span></span></span></div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div data-se="o-form-fieldset-rememberMe" class="o-form-fieldset o-form-label-top">
                                          <div data-se="o-form-input-container" class="o-form-input">
                                             <span data-se="o-form-input-rememberMe" class="o-form-input-name-rememberMe">
                                                <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="input44"><label for="input44" data-se-for-name="rememberMe">Keep me signed in</label></div>
                                             </span>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="o-form-button-bar"><input class="button button-primary" type="submit" value="Sign in" data-type="save"></div>
                              </form>
                           </div>
                           <div class="siw-main-footer">
                              <div class="auth-footer"><a data-se="forgot-password" href="#" class="link js-forgot-password">Forgot password?</a><a data-se="help" href="https://dev-15481137.okta.com/help/login" class="link js-help">Help</a></div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </main>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-abf56ef8="" class="logo-block-small">
         <img data-v-abf56ef8="" src="/src/assets/img/chimney-servicing.jpg" class="logo-background" alt="">
         <div data-v-abf56ef8="" class="logo-container"><img data-v-abf56ef8="" class="ARMS-Logo" src="/src/assets/img/SWEEPACHIM-WEBSITE-BLACK.png" alt="Avatar"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

and the associated css is as follows:

```
    #okta-signin-container{
     display: grid;
     height: 100vh;
     place-items: center;
     padding: 25px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 #okta-sign-in{
     border: none !important;
     font-family: $typography-font-family !important;
}
 #okta-sign-in .auth-content {
     padding: 0px;
}
 #okta-sign-in.auth-container {
     width:100%;
     max-width: 300px;
}
 #okta-sign-in.auth-container h2, #okta-sign-in.auth-container h3 {
     color: #5e5e5e;
     font-weight: 600;
}
 #okta-sign-in .auth-org-logo {
     display: none;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-height: 100px;
     max-width: 100%;
}
 .mobile #okta-sign-in .auth-org-logo {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-height: 100px;
     max-width: 100%;
}
 #okta-sign-in.no-beacon .auth-content {
     padding-top: 30px;
}
 #okta-signin-container #okta-sign-in.auth-container .okta-sign-in-header {
     padding: 0px;
}
 #okta-signin-container #okta-sign-in.auth-container .okta-sign-in-header {
     border: none !important;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     padding-top: 0px;
}
 #okta-sign-in.auth-container .button-primary {
     background-color: $primary;
     background: $primary;
     border: none;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15), inset 0 1px 0 0 hsla(0,0%,100%,.1);
     color: #fff;
}
 #okta-sign-in.auth-container .button-primary:active, #okta-sign-in.auth-container .button-primary:focus, #okta-sign-in.auth-container .button-primary:hover {
     background-color: $primary-dark;
     background: $primary-dark;
     background-image: none;
     border: none;
     box-shadow: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: all .4s;
}
 #okta-sign-in .o-form-head {
     font-size: 30px;
     line-height: 1.5;
     margin-top: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: none;
}
 .mobile #okta-sign-in .o-form-head {
     font-size: 30px;
     line-height: 1.5;
     margin-top: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: none;
     display: none;
}
 #okta-sign-in.auth-container .okta-form-input-field {
     background-color: #ececec;
     border-color: transparent;
     height: 50px;
}
 #okta-sign-in.auth-container .okta-form-input-field:hover {
     border-color: transparent;
}
 #okta-sign-in.auth-container.main-container {
     background-color: #fff;
     border-color: #ddd #ddd #d8d8d8;
     box-shadow: 0 0px 0 hsla(0,0%,69%,.12);
}
 #okta-sign-in .o-form .input-fix input[type=number]:focus, #okta-sign-in .o-form .input-fix input[type=password]:focus, #okta-sign-in .o-form .input-fix input[type=tel]:focus, #okta-sign-in .o-form .input-fix input[type=text]:focus, #okta-sign-in .o-form .input-fix input[type=textbox]:focus {
     box-shadow: 0 0 3px $primary;
}
 #okta-sign-in .checkedFocus {
     position: absolute;
     overflow: hidden;
     clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
     height: 1px;
     width: 1px;
     margin: -1px;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
}
#inputPreview {
     display: flex;
     gap: 20px;
     justify-content: center;
}
.css-checkbox + label {
     position: relative;
     font-size: 14px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-flex;
     align-items: center;
     height: 22px;
     color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.css-checkbox + label::before {
     content: " ";
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-right: 3px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     background-color: rgb(1, 171, 171);
     border-width: 1px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: rgb(1, 171, 171);
     border-radius: 2px;
     box-shadow: none;
}
.css-checkbox:checked + label::after {
     content: " ";
     background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;
    base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MTIgNTEyIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjZmZmZmZmIiBkPSJNMTczLjg5OCA0MzkuNDA0bC0xNjYuNC0xNjYuNGMtOS45OTctOS45OTctOS45OTctMjYuMjA2IDAtMzYuMjA0bDM2LjIwMy0zNi4yMDRjOS45OTctOS45OTggMjYuMjA3LTkuOTk4IDM2LjIwNCAwTDE5MiAzMTIuNjkgNDMyLjA5NSA3Mi41OTZjOS45OTctOS45OTcgMjYuMjA3LTkuOTk3IDM2LjIwNCAwbDM2LjIwMyAzNi4yMDRjOS45OTcgOS45OTcgOS45OTcgMjYuMjA2IDAgMzYuMjA0bC0yOTQuNCAyOTQuNDAxYy05Ljk5OCA5Ljk5Ny0yNi4yMDcgOS45OTctMzYuMjA0LS4wMDF6Ii8+PC9zdmc+");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 12px 12px;
     background-position: center center;
     position: absolute;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     margin-left: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-size: 10px;
     height: 22px;
     width: 22px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please post the html and css code in which your problem is available so that we can return an answer based on it

Comment: Looks like your page should be scrollable. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what's not working